# confused with typescript syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TS, just some questions on its syntax, below is some code I saw:

```
//type declaration file

declare interface Debug {
    (namespace: string): Debugger
}

declare interface Debugger {
    (...args: string[]): void;
    enabled: boolean;
}

declare var debug: { default: Debug };

export = debug;
```

and below is the index.ts file

```
import debug from "debug";

let db = debug("Example App");
db.enabled = true;
...
```

so my questions are:

1.what's the member in interface `Debug`, it doesn't look like a method as it doesn't have a method name, and it is definitely  not a property, so what is `(namespace: string): Debugger`

2-`debug` is an object, not a method, and  it has a type shape of `{ default: Debug }`, so how come we can use `debug("Example App")`, treating it as a method?

3-why I have to use `export = debug;`? can't we get rid of this and use

```
...
export declare var debug: { default: Debug };
// export = debug;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.what's the member in interface Debug, it doesn't look like a method as it doesn't have a method name, and it is definitely not a property, so what is (namespace: string): Debugger

Debug is a function that takes in a string and returns a Debugger. A more conventional way to write the same thing would be to do:

```
type Debug = (namespace: string) => Debugger
```

This first interface doesn't really need to use this alternate syntax, but the interface in your second question is one where the usefulness shows:

> 2-debug is an object, not a method, and it has a type shape of { default: Debug }, so how come we can use debug("Example App"), treating it as a method?

It is a function. But it also has extra properties on it, which is the advantage of this notation. It's pointing out that you can call it as a function (which accepts an array of strings and returns a void), or you can access its `.enabled` property.

> 3-why I have to use export = debug;? can't we get rid of this and use

That would change it to a named export instead of a default export. That's doable, but changes how you import it.